# How do I embed images in HTML email?

Tags: php, codeigniter, html-email, newsletter

> Duplicates:
>
> [How to embed images in email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312687/how-to-embed-images-in-email)
>
> [How to embed images in html email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851728/how-to-embed-images-in-html-email)
>
> [Embed images for use in email message using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097664/embed-images-for-use-in-email-message-using-php)

I am sending HTML emails using php. I want to use embedded images in the HTML. Is it possible? I have tried lot of different methods, but none are working. Is anyone able to help me please?

Thanks

Comment: I tried this one http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-Email-Using-Embedded-Images-in-HTML-Email-P113.html

Comment: @BenSwinburne : It can't send mail

Comment: @phpcochin: DO NOT write all that code on your own. Get some PHP class that deals with building multipart/MIME emails and supports file attachments. It will make your life **much** easier and probably save you hours of work.

Comment: Send (from your normal email client) a HTML email to yourself and study the source code of the received message. This "example code" will really help you understand the theory.

Comment: @ThiefMaster can u share some examples?

Comment: @EugenRieck The email not sending when it contains embedded images

Comment: I know to send html email but i don't know how to embed images in html mail

Comment: If you have no possibility to send yourself HTML email from your standard email client, you should use somtehing like mail.google.com, study the workings, review your code, then come back here

Comment: Actually i want images in cid format

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the whole url where your image resides
example:

```
<img src='http://www.mydomain.com/imagefolder/image.jpg' alt='my-image' width='' height=''>
```

Comment: Exactly the way i do it except for 1 thing. I always use style="display:block" on all my images to stop a gmail bug (adding space below some images). Consider adding it to your answer? :)

Comment: whatever css you want to write put them as inline css. Thats all

Comment: This post is embedding an image, not accessing it from the Internet

Comment: He asked how to EMBED an image... Thats not embedded...

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really trivial, but with a couple of tries doable.

First of all, learn how to build a multipart email, that has the correct images attached to it. If you can't attach the images, they obviously won't be in the email. Make sure to set the type to `multipart/related`.

Secondly, find out how to set the cid references, in particular the `Content-ID` header of the attachment.

Third, glue it all together.

At each step, do the following:

- *look* at the result
- *send* the email to yourself, and compare it to what you received
- *compare* it to a working example email

Answer (score 2):

I find the best way to send images via email is to encode them with base64.

There are loads of links and tutorials on this but here is this code for Codeigniter should suffice:

```
/* Load email library and file helper */
$this->load->library('email');
$this->load->helper('file');

$this->email->from('whoever@example.com', 'Who Ever'); // Who the email is from
$this->email->to('youremailhere@example.com'); // Who the email is to

$image = "path/to/image"; // image path

$fileExt = get_mime_by_extension($image); // <- what the file helper is used for (to get the mime type)

$this->email->message('<img src="data:'.$fileExt.';base64,'.base64_encode(file_get_contents($image)).'" alt="Test Image" />'); // Get the content of the file, and base64 encode it

if( ! $this->email->send()) {
    // Error message here
} else {
    // Message sent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get a string variable without having to worry about the coding.

If you have *Mozilla Thunderbird*, you can use it to fetch the html image code for you.

I wrote a little tutorial here, complete with a screenshot (it's for powershell, but that doesn't matter for this):

[powershell email with html picture showing red x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818500/powershell-email-with-html-picture-showing-red-x/18008855#18008855)

And again:

[How to embed images in email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312687/how-to-embed-images-in-email/18008898#18008898)