# powershell email with html picture showing red x

Tags: powershell, html-email

I have a powershell script that sends out an email with an picture in the HTML but the picture is showing up as a blank square with a red X on it. I can't seem to figure out why its doing that as the examples I saw online are doing the same thing I am (unless I'm missing something pretty obvious which I think I am). Also, the picture is attached as well to the email and that comes out fine.

Here is the code:

```
    $tool="SQLPLUS"
        $cmdLine = "user/pass@P1 ``@C:\NetworkThresholdTriggers\PuertoRico\BYM\BYM.SQL"
        invoke-expression "$tool $cmdLine"
        $Application = "C:\Autobatch\Spotfire.Dxp.Automation.ClientJobSender.exe"
        $Arguments  = "http://server/spotfireautomation/JobExecutor.asmx C:\NetworkThresholdTriggers\PuertoRico\BYM\BYM_spotfirePDF.xml"
        $CommandLine = "{0} {1}" -f $Application,$Arguments
        invoke-expression $CommandLine
        $file = "C:\NetworkThresholdTriggers\PuertoRico\BYM\BYMTriggeroverview.png"
        $file2 = "C:\NetworkThresholdTriggers\PuertoRico\BYM\BYM.csv"
        $smtpServer = "smtp.server.net"
        $att = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($file)
    $att.ContentType.MediaType = “image/png”
    $att.ContentId = “pic”
        $att2 = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($file2)
        $msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
        $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
        $msg.Attachments.Add($att)
        $msg.Attachments.Add($att2)
        $msg.From = "email"
        $msg.To.Add("toemail")
        $msg.Subject = "CRITICAL Notification for 1XRTT BYM $maxDT"
        $msg.Body = "<p style=’font-family: Calibri, sans-serif’>
                      THIS IS A CRITICAL : Please view the attached CSV file for details.<br />
                     <img src=’cid:pic’ />
                     </p>"
        $msg.IsBodyHTML = $true
        $msg.Priority = [System.Net.Mail.MailPriority]::High
        $smtp.Send($msg)
        $att.Dispose()
        $att2.Dispose()
        invoke-expression "DEL $file"
        invoke-expression "DEL $file2"
```

Comment: Try adding the BASE64 encoding as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312687/how-to-embed-images-in-email)

Comment: how do you do that in powershell? I'm new to powershell and trying to learn it, did some googling but couldn't really find the answer or I couldn't understand it. Also don't know what Base64 is...

Comment: `$att.TransferEncoding = [System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding]::Base64` if it works I'll post as an answer.

Comment: @MDMoore313, that seemed to work on the desktop, but when I view the email on a mobile device, no picture yet....hmmm

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it without worrying about any files or base64 statements or mimes (it's still base64, but you don't have to do anything to get it).

To do this, you need *Mozilla Thunderbird*, you can fetch the html code for an image like this:

1. Copy a bitmap to clipboard.
2. Start a new email message.
3. Paste the image. (don't save the message!!!!!)
4. Double-click on it to get to the image settings dialogue.
5. Look for the "image location" property.
6. Fetch the code and wrap it in an image tag, like this:  `<img src="[image code]"/>`

You should end up with a string of text something like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="" height="211" width="213">
```

You can now use this very same code in powershell.  You can put it anywhere in your string variable that you like.  It will display perfectly (this code will generate a lizard).

You can use this method absolutely anywhere that you would present an html email message - even in your email signatures.  The advantage is that there are no attachments, and there are no links.

A picture is worth a thousand words - look!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I see that you can try is change the following. I had the same issue.

I copied from your code above:

```
$att.ContentId = “pic” to $att.ContentId = “pic.png”
```

and in the image tag change:

```
src=’cid:pic’
```

to

```
src=’pic.png’
```