# PHP - auto-download image in HTML email

Tags: php, html, email

I have a page which is sending an HTML email with the following PHP code:

```
$message = $body;//Create message body
$sender = $sender;//Create sender
$to = $customer_email;//Set who the email is being sent to
$subject = 'Quote - '.$_SESSION['quote_number'];//Subject for email
$headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";//Content-type header for mail() PHP built-in function
$headers .= 'To: '.$to . "\r\n";//To header for mail()
$headers .= 'From: '.$sender . "\r\n";//From header for mail()
$mail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);//Send Email
```

Here is the part of the body with the image:

```
<img src="some_img.gif" alt="Title" width="400" height="55" align="left"/>
```

Right now when the email is sent, the image is not automatically downloaded, you have to right click it and download it. Is there a solution to automatically download this image within the mail() PHP function? If not, what is the easiest way I could do it?

I have done some research on this already, I have already looked at over 4 articles, here are a few that did not make sense to me, so I have not used the code in them. They are also pretty outdated.

[How to embed images in email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312687/how-to-embed-images-in-email)

[Embed images for use in email message using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097664/embed-images-for-use-in-email-message-using-php)

I am not interested in really complex code, for me I cannot stand classes and things like that where I just plain don't understand them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,<BASE64_ENCODED_IMG>" alt="Title" width="400" height="55" align="left"/>
```

`<BASE64_ENCODED_IMG>` should be the result of encoding the source binary of `some_img.gif` into Base64

You can do it on the fly with PHP: `base64_encode(file_get_contents('/path/to/some_img.gif'));`
Or get it done by an online service such http://www.base64-image.de/ and copy&paste the results.

You can find further info regarding this in [Embedding Base64 Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)

**Edit:** This may be obvious but... it is not possible to force the mail client to *display* images. But some clients just avoid to *download* them, so in this case this is a valid workaround.

Comment: I apologize, but I am still a little confused. Do I just paste the second line of code you mentioned with the path to my image in the server, then I can just change the source of my image to the code you mentioned on the first line? I tried that, but it does not seem to be working. If you could expound a little, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You need to get your image base64-encoded. You can do it with PHP or with an online service such http://www.base64-image.de/

Comment: If preventing the display and/or download of graphics in an email is a provider or client feature (such as Gmail or Outlook), then how will this force the display of the graphic?

Comment: @BrianWarshaw You're right, you cannot force the client to 'display' images. But some clients avoid to 'download' images so this way is valid in that cases.

Comment: So you're saying this would cause Outlook, for example, to download the image content with the message? I ask because I can't recall ever receiving mail from an external domain at work that didn't have images blocked initially.

Comment: Yes, the image will be downloaded as part of the message. That doesn't mean Outlook is going to display it but beyond the download you can't do anything.